# The type 'xct:TabView' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

I'm getting the error of the tittle when trying to use [**XCT TabView**](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/README.md).

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022. I installed XCT in my project by running both the commands in NuGet Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Xamarin.CommunityToolkit

Install-Package Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup
```

In NuGet solution manager I selected both packages, I checked every checkbook responding to my projects and I hit "Install".

I get the following errors and warnings though:

```
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyProject'.
```

and

```
Error NU1605 Detected package downgrade: Xamarin.Forms from 5.0.0.2291 to 5.0.0.2196. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
MyProject -> Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup 2.0.0 -> Xamarin.Forms (>= 5.0.0.2291)
MyProject -> Xamarin.Forms (>= 5.0.0.2196)
```

I also added the relative namespace to XAML: `xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit`

By the way, I get the same error too for `xct:TabViewItem` but I additionally get another error for it: `Cannot resolve type "xct:TabViewItem"`

Any ideas?

Comment: Upgrade Xamarin.Forms to 5.0.0.2291 and instal XCT then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had tried to do this and met the same problem as you.

This issue happened because the version of xamarin.forms is too low.  So you can open the nuget package manager to update the xamarin.forms to the lastest version.

You can also download the earlier version of the Xamarin.CommunityToolkit and Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup such as 1.3.1

Comment: I upgraded the Xamarin.Forms to version 5.0.0.2337, which is the latest stable version. Same issue. Then I changed to version 5.0.0.2291 and that fixed the issue! Thanks for your input!

I have one more question by the way: In Tools > NuGet Package Manager the menu item "Package Manager Console" is always there, but the one that opens the Graphical Interface called "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." sometimes is missing and sometimes is present. When does this menu item appear in the menu?

Comment: Unfortunately the errors reappeared when I tried to run the project. Although initially they were not marked as errors in the source code, that happened after trying to run the code. Any other idea?

Comment: Update: The CST package for some reason was missing from the `.csproj` file after the installation. Reinstalling version 2 of the XCT fixed the issue!

Comment: Had your problem been solved? I had update my xamarin.forms to the version 5.0.0.2337 and downloaded the XCT 2.0.0. When I add the xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit to the xaml. the xct:TabViewItem worked well. @Costas

Comment: Yes, check my previous message about `.csproj`. I also tried version 5.0.0.2337 of the Xamarin.Forms and it worked fine too.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me when I selected v2.0.2